# Organizing SQL Queries in Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script I'm creating that will replace an set of SQL Server stored procedures to make the process more efficient.  However, I have a 20-30 queries I need to execute at different points.  To make the main query more simple I organized them into a separate file in a dictionary and created a function to pull the query to be executed.

My question here is there a better way to organize them?  An idea I had was to put them into a table on the SQL Server or is this method best or is there another better method?  Below is an example of what I'm doing now:

```
queryDict = {}
queryDict.update({"dbQuery1": "TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable;\
    INSERT MyTable (Column1, Column2)\
        SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM myTable2;"})
queryDict.update({"dbQuery1": 'SELECT MAX(val) FROM MyTable3;'})

def queryRequest(query):
    return queryDict[query]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Replacing stored procedures with external SQL queries for efficiency seems counterintuitive. What's the main query? What do you mean by "better way"? You could save them into separate files and thus get syntax highlighting but unless you specify what you want to achieve, all responses will be opinion-based.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thank you for your questions.  The reason I'm replacing the stored procedures is they are connecting to remote machines via Linked Servers and I want to remove this dependency.  Thus I'm using Python to pull in the data removing the dependency on Linked Servers.  What the goal of my question is to understand what is the best option for handling these that would be most pythonic or best programming practice.

Comment: One way to manage a number of SQL scripts is putting them into separate files as I mentioned. This way you can track them separately in version control and can edit them properly in a text editor with an associated type and syntax highlighting, as opposed to them just being regular Python strings. It depends however on your workflow if this is the best solution in your case.

Comment: @JanWilamowski that is not an approach I had considered.  Thank you.